# Do you unit test __init__ method if it sets up public attributes of a class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, initialization

I am trying to apply Sandi Metz’s rules of unit testing only the messages that really have influence on the public side of the object and testing all the private stuff indirectly by testing the public stuff.

Thus we avoid testing the implementation and can change it at any time.

My question is this: if my `__init__` method sets up publicly available instance attributes should I unit test it as well.

I am basically not sure if the init should be treated as private method (and believe that if it sets public stuff it should be unit tested).

Example:

```
MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, public_parameter_1, public_param_2)

        self.public_parameter_1 = public_parameter_1
        self.public_parameter_2 = public_parameter_2
```

The test using pytest:

```
def test_instance():

    instance = MyClass(1, 2)

    assert instance.public_parameter_1 == 1
    assert instance.public_parameter_2 == 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, because Python doesn't really have private attributes. I suppose you could test everything that doesn't start with an underscore, or you could test everything, but I usually restrict myself to testing things that require some calculation or logic. In the example you give, I wouldn't bother testing those two simple assignments.

If you want to do something to check your `__init__()` methods, you could use some kind of linting tool to check that all the attributes you access in your other methods are assigned a value during `__init__()`. That's probably more efficient than writing explicit tests for all the attributes.

Comment: Had the same question about testing __init__. This answer makes sense to me but, to clarify one point... seems to me that, if it's just assigning values, __init__  likely inherently gets tested when you test it's methods or subclasses. However, if it has conditional logic in it you probably need to test it explicitly to make sure that conditional logic is operating correctly.